# Delete a particular item from a container in cosmos db java

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have tried:

```
PartitionKey partitionKey = new PartitionKey("/sid");

CosmosItemRequestOptions options = new CosmosItemRequestOptions();

cosmosContainer.deleteItem("dbs/Student/colls/Stu/docs/104", partitionKey, options);
```

But getting error:

```
Aug 24, 2020 4:47:15 PM com.azure.cosmos.implementation.ClientRetryPolicy shouldRetry
SEVERE: locationEndpoint is null because ClientRetryPolicy::onBeforeRequest(.) is not invoked, probably request creation failed due to invalid options, serialization setting, etc.
Aug 24, 2020 4:47:15 PM com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RenameCollectionAwareClientRetryPolicy lambda$shouldRetry$2
SEVERE: onBeforeSendRequest is not invoked, encountered failure due to request being null
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity with the specified id does not exist in the system.
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentServiceRequest.<init>(RxDocumentServiceRequest.java:190)
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentServiceRequest.<init>(RxDocumentServiceRequest.java:218)
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentServiceRequest.<init>(RxDocumentServiceRequest.java:243)
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentServiceRequest.<init>(RxDocumentServiceRequest.java:292)
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentServiceRequest.create(RxDocumentServiceRequest.java:510)
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentClientImpl.deleteDocumentInternal(RxDocumentClientImpl.java:1431)
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentClientImpl.lambda$deleteDocument$33(RxDocumentClientImpl.java:1418)
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentClientImpl$$Lambda$525.0000000012AE2210.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.ObservableHelper.lambda$inlineIfPossibleAsObs$1(ObservableHelper.java:44)
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.ObservableHelper$$Lambda$198.00000000127DD800.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.BackoffRetryUtility.lambda$executeRetry$0(BackoffRetryUtility.java:35)
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.BackoffRetryUtility$$Lambda$80.00000000112EA850.get(Unknown Source)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen.subscribe(FluxRetryWhen.java:79)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoRetryWhen.subscribeOrReturn(MonoRetryWhen.java:46)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:57)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2344)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:162)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:103)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCurrentContext.subscribe(MonoCurrentContext.java:35)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4213)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1679)
    at com.azure.cosmos.CosmosContainer.blockDeleteItemResponse(CosmosContainer.java:236)
    at com.azure.cosmos.CosmosContainer.deleteItem(CosmosContainer.java:344)
    at com.cosmos.poc.POC.deleteItem(POC.java:160)
    at com.cosmos.poc.POC.printListContainers(POC.java:72)
    at com.cosmos.poc.POC.printListDataBases(POC.java:54)
    at com.cosmos.poc.POC.main(POC.java:30)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity with the specified id does not exist in the system.
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentServiceRequest.<init>(RxDocumentServiceRequest.java:190)
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentServiceRequest.<init>(RxDocumentServiceRequest.java:218)
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentServiceRequest.<init>(RxDocumentServiceRequest.java:243)
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentServiceRequest.<init>(RxDocumentServiceRequest.java:292)
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentServiceRequest.create(RxDocumentServiceRequest.java:510)
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentClientImpl.deleteDocumentInternal(RxDocumentClientImpl.java:1431)
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentClientImpl.lambda$deleteDocument$33(RxDocumentClientImpl.java:1418)
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentClientImpl$$Lambda$525.0000000012AE2210.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.ObservableHelper.lambda$inlineIfPossibleAsObs$1(ObservableHelper.java:44)
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.ObservableHelper$$Lambda$198.00000000127DD800.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.BackoffRetryUtility.lambda$executeRetry$0(BackoffRetryUtility.java:35)
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.BackoffRetryUtility$$Lambda$80.00000000112EA850.get(Unknown Source)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen.subscribe(FluxRetryWhen.java:79)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoRetryWhen.subscribeOrReturn(MonoRetryWhen.java:46)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:57)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2344)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:162)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:103)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCurrentContext.subscribe(MonoCurrentContext.java:35)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4213)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1679)
    at com.azure.cosmos.CosmosContainer.blockDeleteItemResponse(CosmosContainer.java:236)
    at com.azure.cosmos.CosmosContainer.deleteItem(CosmosContainer.java:344)
    at com.cosmos.poc.POC.deleteItem(POC.java:160)
    at com.cosmos.poc.POC.printListContainers(POC.java:72)
    at com.cosmos.poc.POC.printListDataBases(POC.java:54)
    at com.cosmos.poc.POC.main(POC.java:30)
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1680)
        ... 6 more
Aug 24, 2020 4:52:11 PM com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentClientImpl$1 getDatabaseAccountFromEndpoint
```

Comment: It seems that you misunderstand partition key path and partition key value.`new PartitionKey("/sid")` should be partition key value,not partition key path(I guess "/sid" is your partition key path).You can refer this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview#choose-partitionkey).

Comment: @SteveZhao yes that seems like the problem here. Thanks Got it resolved

Answer (score 0):

The parameters passed to deleteItem method are not correct in your code snippet.

Parameters:

1st param **itemId**: It should be the **document ID**. You passed the whole hierarchical path.

2nd param **partitionKey**: It should contain the value of the partition key. You passed the field name I guess.

For example, you can refer [this example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-java-sql-api-samples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/azure/cosmos/examples/documentcrud/sync/DocumentCRUDQuickstart.java#L285-L293) for correct usage.

Comment: Thanks for the example it worked, seems like I should use the value of the partition key

Answer (score 0):

cosmosContainer.deleteItem("", new PartitionKey(), options);

your could remove the options argument since you are not configuring it.

cosmosContainer.deleteItem("", new PartitionKey());